# XSLT print in loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to use XSLT to transform XML(1.0) to TXT for people to read

and do it inside 【template match="/">】 area

here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="OutputFile.xslt"?>
<File>
    <Header>
      <A><![CDATA[Order]]></A>
      <B><![CDATA[Add]]></B>
      <C><![CDATA[BN]]></C>
      <D><![CDATA[Comment]]></D>
      <E><![CDATA[Base]]></E>
    </Header>
    <Data>
      <row A="1" B="X" C="11.00000" D="" E="0"/>
      <row A="2" B="X" C="5.00000" D="" E="0"/>
      <row A="3" B="X" C="11.00000" D="" E="0"/>
    </Data>
    <Table>
      <Bin Name ="A1" BinNum="1" BinDesc="Type_S" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A4" BinNum="2" BinDesc="Type_AC3" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A9" BinNum="3" BinDesc="Type_E5" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A12" BinNum="4" BinDesc="Type_E5" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A14" BinNum="5" BinDesc="Type_E5" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A22" BinNum="6" BinDesc="Type_E5" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A23" BinNum="7" BinDesc="Type_E6" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A24" BinNum="8" BinDesc="Type_AF3C" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A56" BinNum="9" BinDesc="Type_none" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A57" BinNum="10" BinDesc="Type_defalt" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A70" BinNum="11" BinDesc="Type_auto" End=""/>
      <Bin Name ="A71" BinNum="0" BinDesc="Type_mau" End=""/>
    </Table>
</File>
```

I need to search Header for [BN] to know it's located in C, 
then search Data/row for attritube C, 
finally use this value to compare BinNum in Table and print the corresponding type

Here's my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2006/xpath-functions">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:text>What I want to print is the value of position 11,5,11</xsl:text>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="/File/Table/Bin[position()=11]/@*[position()=3]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="/File/Table/Bin[position()=5]/@*[position()=3]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="/File/Table/Bin[position()=11]/@*[position()=3]"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>


    <xsl:variable name="BN">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(/File/Header/*[text()='BN']) = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(/File/Header/*[text()='BN']/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="BN_location">
      <xsl:for-each select="/File/Data/row">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:if test="position() =$BN">
              <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>But so far I can only print the number 11,5,11 ~~so sad!</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="/File/Data/row">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:if test="position() =$BN">
          <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
          <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:value-of select="/File/Table/Bin[position()=$BN_location]/@*[position()=2]"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is

```
What I want to print is the value of position 11,5,11
Type_auto
Type_E5
Type_auto

But so far I can only print the number 11,5,11 ~~so sad!
11;
5;
11;
```

any help?  THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using nested for-each.
I hope this helps you.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2006/xpath-functions">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="BN_location" select="name(/File/Header/*[text()='BN'])"/> 

    <xsl:for-each select="/File/Data/row/@*[local-name()=$BN_location]">
        <xsl:variable name="BN_attr" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="/File/Table/Bin[@BinNum = round($BN_attr)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@BinDesc"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired output as follows. First find the node containing `BN` value in the `text()` using the `local-name()` function.

```
<xsl:variable name="BNNode" select="local-name(/File/Header/*[text() = 'BN'])" />
```

Using this node, loop through attributes of `<row>` such that the attribute name matches the node name.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/File/Data/row/@*[local-name() = $BNNode]">
```

Loop through all the `<Bin>` where `@BinNum` matches the value of the attribute received from the above `for-each` loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/File/Table/Bin[@BinNum = number($attrVal)]">
```

Select and print the value of `@BinDesc`.

The complete XSLT is as below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:variable name="BNNode" select="local-name(/File/Header/*[text() = 'BN'])" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/File/Data/row/@*[local-name() = $BNNode]">
            <xsl:variable name="attrVal" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="/File/Table/Bin[@BinNum = number($attrVal)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@BinDesc" />
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
Type_auto
Type_E5
Type_auto
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an (in my opinion) elegant way to do this by using keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="rowAttribsByName" match="Data/row/@*" use="name()"/>
  <xsl:key name="binsByNum" match="Table/Bin" use="@BinNum"/>

  <xsl:template match="/File">
    <xsl:variable name="targetAttribName" select="name(Header/*[. = 'BN'])" />

    <xsl:for-each select="key('rowAttribsByName', $targetAttribName)">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('binsByNum', number())/@BinDesc"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
Type_auto
Type_E5
Type_auto
```